# How to import Cython-generated module from python to C/C++ main file? (programming in C/C++)

Tags: python, c++, c, cython

So I have a function written in python and I followed the steps in Cython Documentation 'Building a Cython module using distutils'. However, it's unclear to me how to use that module that's working in python (by import it) to be embedded in C/C++ ? I just want to compile a C/C++ code that imports a python generated module using Cython (I guess it's a 2 step process)

*To clarify, I have already done all the steps and created an python module from a .pyx source file. But my question is how to integrate that module into an existing C/C++ file.

Answer (score 2):

Just declare the stuff you want to call in c/c++ as `cdef public`

for example:

```
# cymod.pyx
from datetime import datetime

cdef public void print_time():
    print(datetime.now().ctime())
```

When cythonizing `cymod.pyx` to `cymod.c`, a `cymod.h` will be generated as well.

Then make a library, eg: `cymod.lib` (on windows).

In the c codes(main.c):

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "cymod.h"


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
Py_Initialize();  

PyInit_cymod();  // in cymod.h
print_time();    // call the function from cython

Py_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Compile and run(main.exe)

**Note:** main.exe is highly bound to the python environments, one may run into errors such as `cannot find pythonxx.dll`, `Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec`. There are many solutions on this site.

Comment: how do you make the .lib?

Comment: @Steven G I use VS compiler on command line, eg `call vcvarsall amd64`
`cl /c /nologo cymod.c /Ipython-header-path`
`lib cymod.obj `

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the [Cython tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html) this is how Cython is used to *extend* Python with compiled C modules.

1. Separate Cython module is written in Python. Cython will convert this to a static compiled module as if written in C.
2. Use a `setup.py` file to compile Cython module as a `*.so` shared library. This shared library is actually a Python module.

   `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`
3. From regular Python script `import` the Cython module

   `import helloworld`

Cython is normally used to *extend* Python with C. If on the other hand you want to *embed* Python code in your C program this is also possible.
Taking a look at the [official docs on embedding Python into C](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) is a good place to read up on first.

Here is a [github project](https://github.com/cython/cython/tree/master/Demos/embed) explaining how to do that, and [a blog](http://seriously.dontusethiscode.com/2013/04/26/a-medium-level-embedding.html) on how to do that.

Comment: I have done all the steps above. My question is how to integrate that module(in your case helloworld) into a current existing C/C++ file. I would like to use that function. Thanks for the comments though!

Comment: Ok. I added some links on how to embed Python into C. I think the regular use for Cython is to extend Python with C though