# Call function compiled from cythonized C in C++?

Tags: python, c++, c, numpy, cython

As far as I know, here is one of the pipeline of Cythoning python code.

1. Cythonize *.pyx into *.c
2. Use general C compiler to compile c

Ok.
However, I would like to use this in a different way.
Normally the output of this pipeline is a *.pyd(Windows) or *.so(Linux) for python to import. I am wondering if I could **use the output of step 2 in my C++ application directly as one normally calls a function in a c file  from C++.**

The reason for this is that I would like to use numpy in my C++ application since numpy is easy to use and fast.

Thank you

Comment: It's a question about embedding python in c/c++ by cython. I've given an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43876987.

Comment: Hi oz1, thank you so much. : )