# Can I use dynamic library compile with cython in c++?

Tags: python, c++, dll, cython

I have a `cython` file `random.pyx` like this:

```
cdef public int get_random_number():
    return 4
```

with `setup.py` like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension

extensions = [Extension("librandom", ["random.pyx"])]
setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
)
```

Then I get a dynamic library `librandom.so`, now I want to use this `so` file in c++ instead of python.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "random.h"

int main() {
    printf("%d\n",get_random_number());
    return 0;
}
```

now I get error like this when I compile `g++ -o main main.cpp -lrandom -L. -Wl,-rpath,"\$ORIGIN"`:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
random.h:26:1: error: ‘PyMODINIT_FUNC’ does not name a type
 PyMODINIT_FUNC initrandom(void);
```

Comment: You will need to add python-includes as well as python library to your build, also you cannot use the functionality of the cython module without innitializing it first. That answer fills the gap from the cython tutorial and may be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45424720/5769463

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your c codes to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Python.h"
#include "random.h"

int main() {
    Py_Initialize(); 
    PyInit_random(); // see "random.h"
    int r = get_random_number();
    Py_Finalize();
    printf("%d\n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that to run the executable, you cannot get rid of the python environment.

Also see [How to import Cython-generated module from python to C/C++ main file? (programming in C/C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43876987)